# How can I diagnose what is interfering with my Wifi signal?

Tags: network, wifi, macos

I have a mysterious  process on my Macbook pro which I can't isolate which comes around every 5 seconds and interferes with my connectivity.

My ping history looks like this:

```
    4 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=12996 ttl=53 time=93.144 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=12997 ttl=53 time=22.797 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=12998 ttl=53 time=23.122 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=12999 ttl=53 time=23.674 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13000 ttl=53 time=23.827 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13001 ttl=53 time=21.925 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13002 ttl=53 time=22.654 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13003 ttl=53 time=754.820 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13004 ttl=53 time=1448.052 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13005 ttl=53 time=1144.956 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13006 ttl=53 time=165.125 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13007 ttl=53 time=22.109 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13008 ttl=53 time=22.513 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13009 ttl=53 time=23.716 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13010 ttl=53 time=22.804 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13011 ttl=53 time=22.349 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13012 ttl=53 time=21.941 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13014
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13014 ttl=53 time=1200.319 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13015 ttl=53 time=933.177 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13016 ttl=53 time=206.759 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13017 ttl=53 time=23.897 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13018 ttl=53 time=22.536 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=13019 ttl=53 time=21.755 ms
```

I can tell that this is local to my machine (and not the network) because these results don't change when I switch networks and other machines on those networks don't show the same intermittent stagnation.

I have closed every application that I can including the obvious background ones (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.) but the problem persists.

At this point I'm at a loss as to how to pinpoint what service or process is doing this. I'm hoping someone has some remedy or third party tool I can use to isolate the culprit and shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

A request timeout on ICMP (ping) going from your Mac to your your network device simply means that the device, not your Mac failed to respond to the ping request in a given amount of time.  There is a good explanation of that [here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/Networking/The_Request_Timed_Out_Message.html).

This can happen for any number of reasons; network congestion, device load, wifi signal interference, power loss, etc.  Most importantly, **it has absolutely nothing to do with services that are running on your Mac.**

Based on the address you used, it looks like you are pinging google.com.  This means that between your Mac and Google's servers there are a number of "hops" that your packet must go through.  Your Mac to your Wifi is one hop.  Wifi to your router/modem is another hop.  Modem to your providers gateway is another hop and so on until you get to Google.

To see how your hops are performing, issue the command `traceroute google.com` and it will output something similar to the following:

```
    1  pfsense (192.168.10.1)  0.401 ms  0.176 ms  0.223 ms
     2  96.120.36.197 (96.120.36.197)  23.503 ms  8.269 ms  8.470 ms
     3  xe-1-3-0-0-sur02.miramar.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.85.82.157)  9.371 ms  8.740 ms  8.517 ms
     4  xe-11-2-2-0-sur03.miramar.fl.pompano.comcast.net (69.139.183.46)  10.091 ms
        xe-11-2-0-0-sur03.miramar.fl.pompano.comcast.net (69.139.183.14)  20.572 ms
        xe-11-1-1-0-sur03.miramar.fl.pompano.comcast.net (69.139.183.177)  9.440 ms
     5  te-9-1-ur01.wellington.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.85.219.25)  16.879 ms  9.370 ms
        xe-1-0-7-0-ar02.stuart.fl.pompano.comcast.net (68.85.219.29)  16.575 ms
     6  be-20214-cr02.miami.fl.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.90.205)  10.963 ms  12.427 ms  11.617 ms
     7  68.86.82.74 (68.86.82.74)  10.475 ms  11.337 ms  9.979 ms
     8  23.30.207.242 (23.30.207.242)  47.521 ms  45.935 ms  47.899 ms
     9  209.85.241.136 (209.85.241.136)  10.958 ms  10.625 ms  10.479 ms
    10  216.239.42.79 (216.239.42.79)  10.616 ms  11.121 ms  10.590 ms
    11  mia07s35-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.192.110)  17.763 ms  16.857 ms  11.290 ms
traceroute to google.com (216.58.192.110), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
```

That's my currently traceroute for Google.  Yours will definitely be different.  Either way, anything in between could be contributing to a dropped packet which is the request timeout error you are seeing.

Comment: thanks, but  you misunderstand. Look at my ping history. There's a persistent, predictable, and never-ending interference going on that is being caused by something running on my mac. When I start in Safe Mode it goes away.  When I restart in normal mode, it returns.  As it happens, this interference is hampering my ability to use Google Hangouts or any other service that needs a reliable persistent connection. My connection is 100% healthy and all other machines on my network don't experience this.

Comment: to be clear when I say "my connection is 100% healthy" I'm referring to my router's connection to the internet. This problem is absolutely positively being caused by some hidden process running on my computer. I just don't know how to figure out what that process is.

Comment: That doesn't change what the error is referring to - which is ***the remote device*** didn't respond to the message.  Ping just tells you if your machine can reach another machine.  You need to first run traceroute

Comment: @Allen, I'm sorry but you are mistaken. My traceroutes come back as totally healthy. Something is bogging down the Network card on my computer preventing it from operating as normal every 5 seconds for about 5 seconds.

Comment: How do you know your connection is 100% healthy?  How do you know that the connection between your cable provider and Google is healthy?

Comment: because I have 7 other machines on this network none of which exhibit the same problem and when I put my machine into safe-mode the problem goes away.

Comment: you have to keep running traceroute.  It's the same protocol as ping (ICMP)

Comment: oh, and also because when I run pings and traceroutes directly from the Router to the internet this problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39530/discussion-between-allan-and-dr-dredel).